# How to count then remove duplicated from for each loop?

Tags: php, foreach, duplicates

I am echoing out a column called `skill_tagging` removing the spaces and some punctuation symbols. However what I'm aiming to do is to count the duplicates the remove/merge them.

Output example: 
item (4) item (15) item(2)

```
<?php

while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    $skill_tagging = $row['skill_tagging'];
    $count         = "???";
    if ($skill_tagging !== null) {

        $chars = preg_quote('|/\.,:;_+', '/');
        $lines = preg_split('/[' . $chars . ']/', $skill_tagging);

        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            echo "<span class='tag_count'>" . $count . "</span><span value='$line'  class='tag_item_search'>" . $line . "</span>";
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Dubs of `$row` or dubs of `$line`?

Comment: Duplicates of `$line`

Comment: Tip: If you are working with arrays then you can use `array_count_values()` and `array_unique()`

Comment: So, counting via `$result = array_count_values($lines)` and removing via `$lines = array_unique($lines)`;

Comment: If `$lines = array_unique($lines)` then it'll remove the preg_split. I tried this and I came up with an error saying `array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove the duplicates and use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to count them

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, how can I integrate that into what I already have, If you could just give me the gist would be most grateful?

Comment: `$skill_tagging = $row['skill_tagging'];    
$skill_unique = array_unique($skill_tagging);  
$count = array_diff($skill_tagging, $skill_unique);`